# Custom Global Store using React.js context and hooks

Tags: javascript, react.js, redux, state

I wanted to use an external global state to a React.js application with a redux-like sort of pattern (with reducers, actions, etc). However, I don't want to use redux itself, as it's just a small project and redux might be too much boilerplate.

Below is a sort of imitation of Redux with React.js Hooks and State. It's a variation of a design found in [this article](https://medium.com/simply/state-management-with-react-hooks-and-context-api-at-10-lines-of-code-baf6be8302c)

```
// src/store/index.js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer} from "react";
import { initialAppState } from "./types";
import { reducer } from "./reducers";

// Redux Mini :)

let dispatchOuter;

const StateContext = createContext(initialAppState);

export const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialAppState);
  dispatchOuter = dispatch;
  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={state}>{children}</StateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useStore = () => [
  useContext(StateContext),
  dispatchOuter,
];
```

Usage:

```
// src/index.js
ReactDOM.render(
  <StateProvider>
    <ExampleComponent/>
  </StateProvider>,
  document.getElementByID("root")
);
```

```
// src/components/ExampleComponent.js
export function ExampleComponent() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useStore();
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={() => {dispatch({type: "INCREMENT_CLICKS"})}}/>
      <span>{state.clicks}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `StateProvider` component is actually a `StateContext.Provider`, which provides context accessed by the `useStore()`. With some initial tests it seems to work pretty well.

Are there any major flaws with this design? Any changes you would suggest? Will I be shooting myself in the foot down the road using this pattern?